# Ugly usage of hyperlink in GWT

Tags: gwt, hyperlink

The hyperlinks I was imagining is something like this as a header:

```
Foo | Bar | Baz
```

This is how I am doing it:

```
Hyperlink foo = new Hyperlink("Foo", "foo");
Hyperlink bar = new Hyperlink("Bar", "bar");
Label spacer = new Label(" | ");

header.add(statistics);
header.add(spacer);
header.add(admin);
RootPanel.get("headerDiv").add(header);
```

It still ends up looking like this (header is a horizontal panel, headerDiv is a Division on the html page):

```
Foo|Bar
```

without the whitespace. I googled a lot, but none seem to address what I am looking for. I also tried Anchors, but that was of no use either. Is there any elegant way of executing this?

Comment: Why don't you try CSS margin/padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the `HorizontalPanel.setSpacing` method I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, that helps with the spacing. thanks. also, i am more concerned if this is a good way of doing it.